# Unity PUN 2 Get Room Playercount Without Joining The Room

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

i want to have a little player count next to each room in my room list but getting the playercount using `playerCount.text = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length.ToString();`
wouldnt work because it will return 0 since you're not in a room yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Room has a PlayerCount property

> `byte`    `PlayerCount`[get] The count of players in this Room (using this.Players.Count)

However, it seems to conflict with the `Players` property referenced above (*`using this.Players.Count`*).

> `Dictionary<int, Player>` `Players`[get] *`While inside a Room`*, this is the list of players who are also in that room.

I would expect `thisRoom.PlayerCount` to work as expected, even though the documentation seems to state otherwise.

Comment: oh i didnt know that the PlayerCount property existed, i replaced PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length    to   playercount.text = info.PlayerCount.ToString(); 
and that worked really well, thank you so much!!